# How to make an SKSpriteNode to walk smoothly on bumpy terrain?

Tags: sprite-kit

curious on how I would make a SKSpriteNode walk smoothly across bumpy terrain (Image below evaluating "Bumpy Terrain")
[image]

I also want the image to have an SKPhysicsBody. How can I possibly do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having just done that (in Unity) the basic premise is as follows:

- cast a ray downwards from the center of the body to its "feet" (ie ray length is equal to half height of the body/node)
- if the ray intersects with a body, check if the body is "walkable" (ie somehow defined as a ground body, for simplicity you can just check if the body is non-dynamic, for more fine-grained control compare the category and contact bitmasks of the intersecting bodies)
- if you found an intersecting, walkable body, set the body's position to where the ray hit the other body, plus half the body/node's height

In Sprite Kit the only way to get the intersection point from a raycast is to use `enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:end:usingBlock:` of the [SKPhysicsWorld](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsWorld/enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart%3aend%3ausingBlock%3a) class. If your character can only walk up straight (ie he won't rotate to adapt to the terrain, and the terrain doesn't have "loops") you only need to check the Y coordinate of the intersection point.

Say your node's position is at Y=340 and the ray intersects at Y=310 and your node's height is 80 then:

```
(340 - 310) + 80 / 2 = 70
```

Then 70 is the distance from the floor your player should be positioned at, to be exact it's the Y coordinate where the ray hit the floor (310) plus this 70 which gives you Y=380 as the new height. Keep the X coord and change the Y coord as you walk over the plane.

Of course the ground plane needs to be a physics body, specifically using an edge shaped body. There are tools that let you design those points from shapes, most prominently PhysicsEditor. But for a start you can experiment with a single line segment, sloped at an angle to test if your character is properly walking the plane up or down.

Note that if you are using physics you should probably set the physics body's velocity to 0,0 after you determined a ground hit, otherwise velocity may accumulate and the body eventually falls through the floor, or can't jump, or do other weird stuff.

Comment: Would I still be setting the physics bodies `CategoryBitMask` and so on or does the ray casting do all the work? @LearnCocos2D

Comment: As far as I understand it, the ray cast will get you all the bodies it hits, and then you have to test if the enumerated body should actually be considered a collision or not. For instance it will probably return the player body itself as the first result.